# vsan tag on Server Fault

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a tag [vsan](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vsan) on Server Fault without any usage guidance. 7 out of 11 are about a specific product: VMware VSAN.

Since tags for other VMware products include the company ([vmware-esxi](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-esxi), [vmware-vsphere](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-vsphere), [vmware-vcenter](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-vcenter)...) I think there should be a tag [vmware-vsan](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-vsan). Is it OK if I create this tag and re-tag the questions that are, in my opinion, product specific or is there a better way? Or is there a reason to not create a tag [vmware-vsan](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-vsan)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems perfectly fine to me. It will give better visibility to questions regarding VMware vSAN.

It might also be a good idea to create a tag [starwind-vsan](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/starwind-vsan) for the few questions regarding that product, and then leave the remainder tagged as [vsan](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vsan) if there are any left.